# Open excel sheet from form

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a form with several command buttons which open specifics worksheets. The problem is when I open an excel file from the command button, if the form is not hidden then I'm not able to click on the opened file(Its not activated)

Even if I hide the form, I need to manually goto that file from taskbar it doesn't get activated.

The problem is:

1. I don't want my form to be hidden because I want the user to be able to open multiple sheets
2. The opened sheet doesn't get activated.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:/power system design/foo.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False)
    UserForm1.Hide
    Wb.Activate
    Wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: A few options based upon what you want to achieve, but I'd suggest investigating the ShowModal property of your form. And possibly making a new instance of Excel.Application in order to open the file.

Comment: @DanielCook Sorry but I'm not aware of the ShowModal property of the form. Is there any "shortcut" alternative because I need to release the sheet quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick way to accomplish what you said you wanted done. It may not be the best way, but you should be able to drop it in and run with it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xls As Excel.Application
    set xls = new Excel.Application
    xls.Workbooks.Open "D:/power system design/foo.xlsx", ,False
    xls.Visible = true
End Sub
```

or if you want to work with the opened workbook

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xls As Excel.Application
    Dim wb as Excel.Workbook
    set xls = new Excel.Application
    set wb = xls.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:/power system design/foo.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False)
    xls.Visible = true
End Sub
```

This will result in the sheet being opened in a new Excel application window.

Comment: It says syntax error for `xls.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:/power system design", ReadOnly:=False)`

Comment: It works if I add `Dim wb as Excel.workbook` and then `Set wb =xls.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:/power system design", ReadOnly:=False)`

Comment: Ah, right. Because of the parenthesis, VBA tries to use the returned object. I'll update the code to not error.